# Search for part of a word in a range of cells not exact phrase

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering if someone can help me. I have created a macro that will search my worksheet for any cells that displays a specific word, and then display the row.

This works completely fine and did what i wanted it to do...

What i am wanting to do is search my worksheet for any cell that displays PART of a word or phrase and displays the row

for example...
At the moment if i search for "Men in Black" it will only display any row that has the phrase "Men in Black" in Column B.

What i want it to do is also Display "Men in Black 2" and Men in Black 3" as well as "Men in Black" when using the search "Men in Black" (i could also just search for "Black". It would also display Men In Black 1, 2 and 3... but would also display rows containing "Black Dog"

If i am wanting to display the rows containing "The Black Cauldron" i would like to be able to just search for "Cauldron" rather than the whole exact phrase. Yes i am aware that i will get anything that has the word Cauldron in it but thats fine.

What i am trying to achieve is not having to type the exact phrase to get the search result.

Below is my current code... thanks in advance!

```
Option Compare Text

Sub finddata()

Dim itemname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("PRICES").Range("G5:K100").ClearContents

itemname = Sheets("PRICES").Range("H2").Value
finalrow = Sheets("PRICES").Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = itemname Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        Range("G100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
Next i

Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Like" and wildcards "*" to find a word, or part of a word in a cell.

Try this code:

---

```
Option Compare Text

Sub finddata()

Dim itemname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("PRICES").Range("G5:K100").ClearContents

itemname = Sheets("PRICES").Range("H2").Value
finalrow = Sheets("PRICES").Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2).value like "*" & itemname & "*" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
    Range("G100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

---

The only changes are on this line:

```
If Cells(i, 2) = itemname Then
```

Which I've changed to:

```
If Cells(i, 2).value like "*" & itemname & "*" Then
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend!! That worked perfectly... Thankyou so much!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked! Please upvote and select this as your chosen answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: done! thanks again